# Using generator send with for semantics

Tags: python-3.x, generator, yield

I would like to use the following generator with a `for` loop instead of a `while`, exploiting the fact that `for` implicitly calls `next()` and handles `StopIteration` on generators:

```
def gen():
    failures = 0
    ret = 0
    while True:
        yield ret
        x = yield
        ret += 1
        if not x:
            failures += 1
            if failures == 20:
                break
```

The main idea of this generator is sending a value and expecting a "feedbak" on the value. After 20 negative feedbacks, the generator terminates.

Now, I would expect this to be easily usable in a `for` loop as follows:

```
g = gen()
for k in g:
    print(k)
    if k % 2:
        g.send(False)
    else:
        g.send(True)
```

the idea being `yield ret` is done every time the `for` implicitly calls `next()` and `x = yield` is done every time `g.send()` is called. Unfortunately, this does not work: in fact, for some reason, the generator always receives `None` from the send.
The only way I managed to get this to work is changing the generator as follows:

```
def gen():
    failures = 0
    ret = 0
    while True:
        x = yield ret  # this changes
        ret += 1
        if not x:
            failures += 1
            if failures == 20:
                break
```

and using it like this:

```
g = gen()
k = g.send(None)
while True:
    try:
        print(k)
        if k % 2:
            k = g.send(False)
        else:
            k = g.send(True)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Is there any way to accomplish this using `for` semantics to implicitly handle the generator's termination?

Comment: `x = yield` will always yield `None`, because there's nothing after the statement